# How to report post-hoc comparisons against 0?

Tags: r, anova, t-test, lsmeans

In the following code, I fitted an anova model (`aov$aov` below) and tried to compare the marginal mean of each condition against 0 (using `emmeans`) using `glht` to test general linear hypothesis.

My current reporting is the following. So I am wondering what are the p-values generated before applying Holm-Bonferroni correction? How could you add it to the report?

> Before we conducted pairwise comparisons across conditions, we used the ANOVA model to calculate estimated marginal means of all conditions and performed multiple comparisons with Holm-Bonferroni correction \cite{79holm} to test whether these means significantly deviate from 0 ($H_0:\mu=0$).

```
summary(as.glht(emmeans(aov$aov, ~ `ExecutionType` | `HeadShaking`)), test=adjusted(type="holm"))
```

The output is this:

```
$`HeadShaking = With Headshake`

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Linear Hypotheses:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
No Cue == 0         1.6129     0.1795   8.984  < 2e-16 ***
Look == 0           1.2258     0.1795   6.828 3.60e-11 ***
Look & Point == 0   1.4194     0.1795   7.906 6.35e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- holm method)


$`HeadShaking = Without Headshake`

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Linear Hypotheses:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
No Cue == 0         1.1774     0.1795   6.558 5.58e-10 ***
Look == 0           0.6613     0.1795   3.683 0.000265 ***
Look & Point == 0   0.7419     0.1795   4.132 8.90e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- holm method)
```

Comment: Does `test=adjusted(type="none")` work?

Comment: Yes. I just edited my question. My previous output is done by `test=adjusted(type="none")`, so it works.

Comment: Is it a t test?